# Does "Super Street Fighter IV Arcade Edition" also contain the original SSF4?

Tags: super-street-fighter-iv

I just got [Super Street Fighter IV Arcade Edition](http://store.steampowered.com/app/45760/) on PC *(note: not to be confused with [Street Fighter IV](http://store.steampowered.com/app/21660), which is a different game)*.

When I go to "Challenge -> Trial", it says:

> Trial Mode is not compatible with
>   Super Street Fighter IV Arcade Edition.
>   The game will temporarily switch to
>   Super Street Fighter IV Original.

My questions are:

- Does SSF4AE also contain the SSF4?
- Is it possible to switch between the Arcade Edition and the Original? How? Do I need to unlock it?

Remember, since I just got this game, I haven't unlocked anything and I don't even know what are the unlockables.

[image: Message shown after entering the Trial mode]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this was a feature on the console releases, but you can't switch back and forth on the PC version, as [this review](http://pc.ign.com/articles/118/1181213p1.html) from IGN laments:

> What's slightly disappointing about this Arcade Edition is that it doesn't give you the option to swap back to the Super rule set and 36 fighter roster. I point this out because if you download the Arcade Edition on Xbox 360 or PlayStation 3 as an upgrade to Super Street Fighter IV, you're given the ability to swap back and forth between Super and Arcade sets.